# dotnet core IDistributedCache redis refresh not work

Tags: asp.net-core, distributed-cache

Version of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis  {1.1.1}, my simple code:

```
DistributedCacheEntryOptions userExpire = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds() + 300
};
_cache.SetString("sessionX", "Bill", userExpire);

// refresh sessionX not work 
_cache.Refresh("sessionX");
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

It works, you are just not patient enough to wait 47 years!

you would probably want to try this:
`AbsoluteExpiration =  DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(300);`

ToUnixTimeSeconds is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z which is ~47 years.

Setting that in seconds as the cache absolute expiration means to cache for 47 years.

Comment: Hi @Csaba, thanks for answer. I finally found the mistake I had made is that I did not set the "SlidingExpiration" property, so Refresh won't work. Found it at [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/RedisCache.cs)